# Metric of the real numbers for which it is not complete

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Is there a metric for which the real numbers are not complete? Clearly this is true if there is any non-complete uncountable metric space (though I haven't been able to find an example for this neither), but I am specially interested if the metric is something that can be written with the usual functions and operations in the reals.

Comment: Well, just take the usual metric on $\mathbb R$ and remove one point.

Comment: Let $f:\Bbb R\to(-1,1)$ be a homeomorpism and define $d(x,y)=|f(x)-f(y)|$. (Then $(1,2,3,\dots$) is a divergent Cauchy sequence.)

Comment: @ThomasShelby  As the OP points out (implicitly), all you need is an incomplete metric space which, as a set, is in bijection with $\mathbb R$.  True, the OP refers to an "incomplete uncountable metric space", but here I think "uncountable" is intended to mean "bijective with $\mathbb R$".